Did Moses receive the entire Law at Sinai or was it progressively revealed?
There are commandments and ordinances throughout Leviticus, Numbers and Deuteronomy. Did Moses already have knowledge of these commands prior to whatever timeline the commands were revealed in their respective books?

All we can say is that Ex 19-23 was revealed at Sinai.  Deuteronomy was a series of four speeches by Moses 39 years later before he died.  The book of Deuteronomy is just an expansion of the 10 commandments.

Moses was not omniscient. So if some commandments are narrated as having been given after the Sinai event, we may presume that Moses did not already have knowledge of them.

Many commandments are described as revelations from God to Moses long after the Sinai event. For example the Book of Leviticus begins with the following verses:

The Lord called Moses, and spoke to him from the tent of meeting: 2
Speak to the Israelites and tell them...

Some of these commands are found in Exodus as part of the Sinai revelation but many are clarifications or new information about priestly tradition and what we would call civil law. These may have been revealed to Moses during the period covered by Leviticus as kind of praxis as issues came up in performing the rites prescribed at Sinai. Other commandments in Leviticus are moral teachings not stipulated at Sinai - most famously but not limited to: "love your neighbor as yourself." (Leviticus 19:18)
A similar principle applies to commandments given in other books of the Torah. For example in Numbers 18 God reveals (to Aaron, not Moses) various laws about tithing and Num. 30 institutes laws about religious vows. Deuteronomy especially tends to look forward to life in Canaan as well as reiterating what had been revealed at Sinai. An important example if found in Deut. 12:10, which instructs that sacrifices may not be made outside of one special temple, later identified as Jerusalem in Jewish tradition and Gerizim for the Samaritans.

After you have crossed the Jordan and dwell in the land which the
Lord, your God, is giving you as a heritage, when he has given you
rest from all your enemies round about and you live there in security,
11 then to the place which the Lord, your God, chooses as the dwelling
place for his name you shall bring all that I command you: your burnt
offerings and sacrifices, your tithes and personal contributions, and
every special offering you have vowed to the Lord.

In addition, some critics often propose that there are several sources of the various commandments. Many are thought to be found in relatively early sources but others come from the later "D" (Deuteronomist) and "P" (priestly) sources.
